# Include prefixes with lXML when using ElementTree

Tags: python, html, outlook, tags, lxml

I'm currently parsing HTML formatted emails created in Outlook. I've been generating the path to elements, but some tags have prefixes like <o:p>. The code below parses <o:p> out as a <p> tag (dropping the prefix), but I'm trying to include the entire <o:p>. Is there any way to force this in lXML?

As an example

`<body lang=EN-US link="#0563C1" vlink="#954F72"><div class=WordSection1><p class=MsoNormal>Hi Joe<o:p></o:p>`

parses as

`/html/body/div/p[1]/p`

but I'm trying to get

`/html/body/div/p[1]/o:p`

```
parser = etree.HTMLParser()
etree.ElementTree.register_namespace('<o>')

try:
    root = etree.fromstring(messageHTML2, parser)
    print(root)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

tree = etree.ElementTree(root)
for e in root.iter():
    pathItemList.append(tree.getpath(e))
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this issue was gross, but worked.

Because getting the path removes the prefix (anything before the semicolon), I decided to simply change all semicolons to a specific text string that would otherwise be unlikely to appear (for my case I simply used SEMICOLONHERE, but depending on what you are working with it may need to be more obscure).

The case above would look like: `<body lang=EN-US link="#0563C1" vlink="#954F72"><div class=WordSection1><p class=MsoNormal>Hi Joe<oSEMICOLONHEREp></oSEMICOLONHEREp>`, which is vaild.

By changing the semicolon to text, when parsed it believes that it is all just one tag. Once you have the final output, just doing a replace on that specific string to return it to a semicolon will yield the desired output.